# Text Editor Scratch

Tags: 14.04, command-line, text, editor

I am trying to install a text editor named **Scratch**,which is the default text editor in Elementary OS.

I've done the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scratch-text-editor
```

When I try the last command it throws me some kind of error and i can't proceed:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 scratch-text-editor : Depends: libgranite2 (>= 0.3.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-1 (>= 3.14.3) but 3.10.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                       Depends: libvala-0.26-0 (>= 0.17.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libscratchcore0 (= 2.2.0~r1523+pkg77~daily~ubuntu0.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.02 64 bit.

Comment: Relevant re: dependencies: http://decathorpe.com/post/152565292380/a-report-on-packaging-pantheon-for-fedora

Answer (score 0):

**If you really want to... and don't want to download pantheon desktop and it's software**:

- [libgranite2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/libgranite2)
- [libgtksourceview-3.0-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libgtksourceview-3.0-1)
- [libvala-0.26-0-dbg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/debug/libvala-0.26-0-dbg)
- [libsratchcore0](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+sourcepub/4938139/+listing-archive-extra)

Install those `.deb` packages manually, you will probably end up installing other dependencies of those listed above, google them, it doesn't take so much time.
Once I had to do the same, because there was no other way... and it was faster than making terminal to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It's complaining saying the request is impossible and those dependencies won't work on this version of ubuntu.

if it's really necessary try installing it with

```
sudo apt-get install -f scratch-text-editor
```

If its possible it will force the package to install.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Again the same.Does not work.

Comment: try installing the dependencies manually?

Comment: When i try to install the dependecies it says command not found.